# cross browser text wrap within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to have a block of text fit in a div and wrap mid word with a '-' inserted before the break.

Basically have the text wrap around the elem-
ent like that.  Then I can create a block of tex-
t that will automatically wrap around to the be-
ginning when the div id resized

Comment: With CSS only but very limited support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/hyphens

Comment: In practice this isn't going to be very effective anyways because those hyphens are supposed to occur between syllables, not random letters, and detecting syllables is very hard to do.

Comment: as Jason (+1) said, it would be not a cross-browser issue, but a cross-language issue. But who knows. Let's wait for HTML6 and see an implemented *thesaurus* words recognition technology depending on the *lang* attribute `<html lang="en">` :)

Answer (score 0):

The commenters are right. But for what its worth, this is probably the best you are going to get: http://jsfiddle.net/zB47k/

Answer (score 0):

if you don't absolutely need the '-' you can use word wrap

```
.wrap {word-wrap:break-word;}

<div class="wrap">dfkajdlkfjkadjfjadjfladjfkajdkjfkajdfad</div>
```

You could also use the new hyphens spec, but it has limited browser support:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens

```
-ms-hyphens: auto;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

While waiting cross-browser native support for hyphenation one way could be:
http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/

Or add soft-hyphens serverside (php):
http://phphyphenator.yellowgreen.de/

I have self used method of adding soft-hyphens in php (using the above library), because site is multi-language one and all language-related stuff occurs serverside.